# Tableviewcell data won't translate to another view controller

Tags: json, swift, parsing, core-data, shopping-cart

I did a parse json in my listingshopvc and it shows.Now I want to select a row and it pops up another view controller but there's error just a blank page with no error. I just want to press a row and convert it to show up on another view controller.

I have listing in the following view controller: ListingShopVc,ProductDetail,TableCellData

ListingShopVC

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ListingShopVC: UIViewController,   UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var creditsdisplay: UILabel!

var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as!  AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
var myUser:[User] = []
var mySecond:[Product] = []

var id:String = ""
var name:String = ""
var price:Double = 0.0
var image:String = ""
var details:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    fetch()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    extracted()
    creditsdisplay.text = "You have 200 credits"
    
    
}
// MARK: - Table view data source

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return mySecond.count
    
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "hello", for: indexPath) as! TableCellData

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.shopTitle.text = mySecond[indexPath.row].name
    cell.shopPrice.text = "$" + String(mySecond[indexPath.row].price) + "0"
    cell.shopDesc.text = mySecond[indexPath.row].description
    
    if let url = URL(string: mySecond[indexPath.row].image){
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
            if let data = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.shopImageView.image = image
                
            }
        }
        }
    }

    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    id  = mySecond[indexPath.row].id
    name = mySecond[indexPath.row].name
    price = mySecond[indexPath.row].price
    details = mySecond[indexPath.row].description
    image = mySecond[indexPath.row].image
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toDetails", sender: self)
    
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDetails"{
        let vc = segue.destination as! ProductDetail
        
        vc.productPicture = image
        vc.productName = name
        vc.productPrice = price
        vc.productDetails = details
        vc.productID = id
        print(vc.productName)
    }
}


func extracted(){
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://rajeshrmohan.com/sport.json")
    else {return}
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){
        (data,response,error) in
        guard let dataResponse = data,
              error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let model:[Product] = try decoder.decode([Product].self, from: dataResponse)
            //print(model)
            
            for i in 0..<model.count{
                self.mySecond.append(model[i])
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch let parsingError {
            print("Error", parsingError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

func fetch(){
    userList = try! context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
    
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

TableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class TableCellData: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet weak var shopImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var shopTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var shopPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var shopDesc: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    
    
}



override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

ProductDetail

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ProductDetail: UIViewController {

var context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

var myArray:[Cart] = []
var mySecondArray:[Products] = []

var newTots:Double = 0.0


@IBOutlet weak var AddImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var AddTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var AddPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var AddDesc: UILabel!

var productID = String()
var productName = String()
var productPrice:Double = 0.0
var productPicture = String()
var productDetails:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        AddTitle.text = productName
        AddDesc.text = productDetails
        AddPrice.text = String(productPrice)
        if let imageUrl = URL(string: productPicture),
        let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl) {
        AddImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        }
    
}


@IBAction func add2Cart(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let neww = Cart(context: context)
    neww.image = productPicture
    neww.name = productName
    neww.desc = productDetails
    neww.price = productPrice
    neww.total = productPrice
    
    try! context.save()
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoCheckout", sender: nil)
}

func fetch(){
    self.mySecondArray = try! context.fetch(Products.fetchRequest())
} 
}
```

What it shows it this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWUt0.png

Comment: Did you debug the viewDidLoad of ProductDetail and check if product information is available when viewDidLoad is called? My best guess is that its not..try placing the code in viewWillAppear..

Comment: Try moving below code to viewWillApppear not viewDidAppear
AddTitle.text = productName
        AddDesc.text = productDetails
        AddPrice.text = String(productPrice)
        if let imageUrl = URL(string: productPicture),
        let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl) {
        AddImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        }

Comment: Same problem. Ive tried both viewwillappear and viewdidappear in case and same output. Just a blank page with no errors

Answer (score 0):

-> You just need to call a delegate method of table view didSelectRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let tag = projectEquipmentList?[indexPath.row].tag // Object data to take in next VC
        let QR = R.storyboard.main.qrScannerVC()! // View Controller
        QR.manageVC(projectEquipmentTag: tag!) // setter method of View controller to set data
        navigationController?.pushViewController(QR, animated: true) // push to next view controller 
        
    }
```